# Connect multiple Django web applications to a single MySQL database

Tags: mysql, django, flask

In order to save costs (I have limited funds at the moment), I hope to connect multiple Django web applications (or one or two with Flask) up to a single MySQL database online.

Is this possible? Will it cause problems with the "sessions" tables? Will I need to add additional code to distinguish different applications?

Comment: Define "single database". You can create multiple databases for separate applications within one MySQL server. If you do that, no worries. If you literally share a single database among several different applications… maybe not so wise.

Comment: Your main problem won't be sessions (you can use a non-database backend for sessions), but other built-in tables (such as `django_migrations`).

Comment: Why not use Django Rest Framework? You don't literally needs to connect to database all you need is an API.

Comment: @romel And where does DRF store the data…?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible, but don't get confused between "database" and "the MySQL host application". MySQL, MariaDB, Postgres, etc., can have *many* databases running on the same backend.

If you have two different Django projects, `project1` and `project2`:

```py
# project1/settings.py
DATABASES = {
   'default': {
       'NAME': 'project1',
       'HOST': 'your.mysql.endpoint',
       ...
   }
}
```

```
# project2/settings.py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'project2',
        'HOST': 'your.mysql.endpoint',
        ...
    }
}
```

If you were to inspect your MySQL instance (via SQL or a GUI tool), `project1` and `project2` are two different top-level "databases". For most intents and purposes, they're independent from one another. They'll have separate tables, migrations, sessions, and so on. Think of them as tenants in an apartment complex: the two Django projects might have the same street address, but different unit numbers and their own living spaces. Same goes for Flask or any other application you want to connect to the same MySQL server.

> Will I need to add additional code to distinguish different applications?

Probably not, assuming that the two projects are totally separate and don't need to share any knowledge of each other.